# How to get dynamicField from solr in java which is of map datatype in cassandra database

Tags: java, solr, solrj, luke

I need to fetch a dynamicField (test_*) from solr engine. I am unable to get the output as it gives nullpointerexception.

```
Map<String,String> myMap = (Map<String,String>) result1.get(i).getFieldValue("test_*");


QueryResponse response1 = solr.query(query); 

SolrDocumentList result1 = response1.getResults(); //result1 is the SolrDocumentList 
for(int i=0; i < result1.size();i++){ //get set varaibles }
```

Comment: Can you debug and see what is null? result1? result1.get(i)?

Comment: QueryResponse response1 = solr.query(query);
SolrDocumentList result1 = response1.getResults();                             for(int i=0; i < result1.size();i++){ //get set varaibles  }                          //result1 is th eSolrDocumentList

Comment: Can you edit your question to include all the code.